# Does ASP.NET have any provision to perform certain 'always on' tasks?

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, webforms

**This is more of a design/architectural question**

I know the question sounds vague but let me explain my applications need.

So I have a windows form which collects certain data from the local machine and sends it to an azure queue regularly. I also have a Web app which pulls data from the queue simultaneously and displays the data. All is well and good here as the  web application works fine . But the web app only pulls data from the queue when I 'launch' it. Is there a way to run this task of processing the data every time ? (like as and when the data is available).

This is a requirement because along with displaying the data, the web app also monitors contents of this data for threshold limit and sends notifications too.
Right now, only if the web app is launched/opened on a client browser, it can send notifications.

Comment: Do take a look at `Azure WebJobs` or `Functions`. They will run the task in the background as and when messages are posted in a queue.

Comment: I'd recommend http://hangfire.io/ - it is designed for this sort of situation.

Comment: @GauravMantri WebJobs was just what I was looking for ! Its perfect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the couple of suggestions, I found Azure WebJobs ideal for my task. A little more research shows Azure Worker Role to be useful too, but setting it up looks more difficult.

Answer (score 0):

you should take a look at SignalR. It is a library which is used for real time communication, there are a lot of strategy for making this real-time communication happen and SignalR implements for you. 
It can be used easily with ASP.NET you should just take a look for some codes to know how to implement in your case but this is your game.